# How to inject code after every description label?

Tags: enumitem, description

With the `format` option, I can inject code in the beginning of every `description` label:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{description}[format={\ ...\ }]
\item[A] Apple
\item[B] Banana
\item[C] Carrot
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image: Code is injected before every description label]

How can I inject code *after* every `description` label, to achieve the following effect?

[image: Code is injected after every description label]

I'm primarily interested in affecting only a single, specific `description` environment, not all of them; but am also interested in the possibility of making the change applicable to all `description` environments.

Comment: Why not use `enumerate` and set the label to `\Alph* ...`?

Comment: @Stephen Because the example I gave in my post is just for illustration purposes. The actual labels I use in my real document are not `A`, `B`, `C`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The value of `format` can be a macro that takes an argument:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand\mydescformat[1]{!!! #1 ...}
\begin{document}
\begin{description}[format=\mydescformat]
\item[A] Apple
\item[B] Banana
\item[C] Carrot
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I am sure this is not a good, but at least a working solution. I explained inline what I did. Basically, I renewed `\item` to add `\addcode` after each label, where `\addcode` is to be defined by the user.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\def\addcode{ Hi! $a+b=c$ :) \ldots} % This will be added after each `\item` (can be changed)
\makeatletter
\let\olditem\item % store old definition
\def\item{\@ifnextchar[{\item@with}{\item@without}} % if optional argument is given, call `\item@with`, else call `\item@without`
\def\item@with[#1]{\olditem[#1\addcode{}]}
\def\item@without{\olditem}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{description}
        \item[A] Apple
        \def\addcode{}
        \item[B] Banana
        \def\addcode{ Note that {[brackets]} need to be wrapped in curly braces }
        \item[C] Carrot
        \def\addcode{ Bye}
        \item[D] Date
    \end{description}
    %
    This will also effect \texttt{itemize} and similar environments.
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Test without
        \item[A] Test with
    \end{itemize}
    Therefore you should initialize \texttt{\textbackslash addcode} with \texttt{\{\}}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]